# How to plot (x,y,z)

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Is there anyway to plot x(from x textbox), y(from y textbox), and z(from z textbox) in vb form?
It is windows application. I have three text boxes that indicates x,y,z coordinate. I was wondering if there is any tool or method to show this point to user.[image]

Comment: I suppose you want to show more than just a point. You might need to show coordinate axes with labels, a filled circle for the point and a label next to the point. In addition, coordinate values may be displayed. Please be specific on what the output should be. The _how_ to "display a point" needs clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main avenues here. 1) Transform the (x,y,z) coordinate into a planar project (x,y) and use [gdi+](/questions/tagged/gdi%2b) to draw on the screen, or 2) Use [opentk](/questions/tagged/opentk) to draw a point directly into an `GLControl`, but you have to setup the viewport and projection first.

It is not very pretty, but here is a proof of concept with `VS2010` using [OpenTK](http://www.opentk.com/).

[image: Form]

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    bool loaded=false;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Vector3 PointCoordinates
    {
        get
        {
            float x=0, y=0, z=0;
            float.TryParse(xTextBox.Text, out x);
            float.TryParse(yTextBox.Text, out y);
            float.TryParse(zTextBox.Text, out z);

            return new Vector3(x, y, z);
        }
        set
        {
            xTextBox.Text=value.X.ToString();
            yTextBox.Text=value.Y.ToString();
            zTextBox.Text=value.Z.ToString();
        }
    }
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        PointCoordinates=new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        loaded=true;
        SetupViewPort();
    }

    private void glControl1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!loaded) return;
        SetupViewPort();
    }

    private void glControl1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        glControl1.MakeCurrent();
        GL.ClearColor(glControl1.BackColor);
        GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit|ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);

        GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);
        GL.LoadIdentity();

        SetupCamera();

        // Draw Coordinate System
        GL.LineWidth(1.5f);
        GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.Lines);
        GL.Color3(Color.Red);
        GL.Vertex3(0, 0, 0);
        GL.Vertex3(1, 0, 0);
        GL.Vertex3(0.85, 0.05, -0.05);
        GL.Vertex3(1, 0, 0);
        GL.Vertex3(0.85, -0.05, 0.05);
        GL.Vertex3(1, 0, 0);
        GL.Color3(Color.Green);
        GL.Vertex3(0, 0, 0);
        GL.Vertex3(0, 1, 0);
        GL.Vertex3(-0.05, 0.85, 0.05);
        GL.Vertex3(0, 1, 0);
        GL.Vertex3(0.05, 0.85, -0.05);
        GL.Vertex3(0, 1, 0);
        GL.Color3(Color.Blue);
        GL.Vertex3(0, 0, 0);
        GL.Vertex3(0, 0, 1);
        GL.Vertex3(-0.05, 0.05, 0.85);
        GL.Vertex3(0, 0, 1);
        GL.Vertex3(0.05, -0.05, 0.85);
        GL.Vertex3(0, 0, 1);
        GL.End();

        // Draw a single point
        var vector=PointCoordinates;
        GL.PointSize(5f);
        GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.Points);
        GL.Color3(Color.Black);
        GL.Vertex3(vector);
        GL.End();
        GL.PointSize(3f);
        GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.Points);
        GL.Color3(Color.Yellow);
        GL.Vertex3(vector);
        GL.End();

        glControl1.SwapBuffers();
    }

    void SetupViewPort()
    {
        float wt=Math.Max(1, glControl1.Width);
        float ht=Math.Max(1, glControl1.Height);
        float sz=(float)Math.Sqrt(ht*wt);
        GL.Viewport((int)(wt-sz)/2, (int)(ht-sz)/2, (int)sz, (int)sz);
        var ortho=Matrix4.CreateOrthographic(
            10f, 10f, 1f, 200f);
        GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);
        GL.LoadMatrix(ref ortho);
    }

    void SetupCamera()
    {
        Matrix4 lookAt=Matrix4.LookAt(
                        10f, 5f, 15f,
                        0f, 0f, 0f,
                        0f, 1f, 0f);
        GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);
        GL.LoadMatrix(ref lookAt);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        glControl1.Refresh();
    }

}
```

Comment: May want to try also `GL.Hint(HintTarget.PointSmoothHint, HintMode.Nicest);` to smooth the point a bit.

Comment: My output will be similar to the picture that you posted above but as you said, I would have multiple points. I already have a form and I want to add this feature on the side of my form. How should I add this to my code? I installed opentk. Do I need to put this folder in specific location to use your code?

Comment: Did you reference `OpenTK` in your project? You need add a reference to `OpenTK.GLControl` also and add a `GLControl` to your existing form. Read the documentation with opentk and post in [SO] any questions.

Comment: hey @ja72 I have a question. For some reasons, when I press the draw button, my plot does not show the point. Do you think that yo can maybe change the code above to vb.net? or do you mind looking at my code?