# Rendering a point or plane in 3D

Tags: c#, .net, 3d, xna

Although my current project is XNA, this question is about the basic mathematics of 3D to 2D mapping. In fact, and for the same reason, let's assume a WinForms graphics surface to draw on.

I have the following configuration:

- Camera position of (x=0, y=0, z=0) and direction vector of (x=0, y=0, z=0).
- A line segment in 3D with the following points: (10, 10, 10), (100, 100, 100).

I want to transform these coordinates and draw them on a 2D surface. So depending on the camera, the line segment should transform from (x1, y1, z1),(x2, y2, z2) to (x1, y1),(x2, y2).

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you have a specific question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to plot (x,y,z)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22701999/how-to-plot-x-y-z)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for an orthogonal or perspective projection. There is a lot of information online if you search for it but here is the gist.

A camera looking at the origin, located a distance `d` along the z-axis will project a point at `(x,y,z)` onto a plane as:

```
// Orthogonal
planar_x = x
planar_y = y

// Perspective
planar_x = x*d/(d-z)
planar_y = y*d/(d-z)
```

### Example

A point at `(10,10,10)` with the camera located a distance of `500` along the z axis will have planar coordinates `(10*500/(500-10), 10*500/(500-10)) = (10.204, 10.204)`

A point at `(10,10,100)` with the camera located a distance of `500` along the z axis will have planar coordinates `(10*500/(500-100), 10*500/(500-100)) = (12.5, 12.5)`

So the closer a shape is to the camera the  larger it appears.

To transform the planar model coordinates to pixel coordinates I use the following scaling

```
scale = max_model_size/Math.Min(Height,Width);
pixel_x = Width/2 + x/scale;
pixel_y = Height/2- y/scale;
```

This is how I can use `GDI` to draw 3D shapes on a windows form.

[image: Form]

Of course if you want to use `OpenGL` then look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22720918/380384) for a similar question.